# how to resize list height in Android Studio according to content?

Tags: android, list, adapter

I'm Starting to get into Android programming more and more, 
and right at the start I had a problem,

I'm creating a simple list with a costume layout and in the String array I'm passing to the string in the list, it some Data is to large to enter and thus, I'm left with a Cut string,

Is there a way to dynamically increase the list block height if the Data is too big to fit in it, so that it will wrap the list perfectly ?

I guess from my learning of code, you could calculate the string length and come up with a solution like that, but is there a more elegant way to fix this ?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Do it programmatically in getView() method. Give your listview a static height, in getview(), for each item assign height as (listview height)/(no of rows)

Comment: show your inflated layout in ListView.

Comment: Can you please share the layout for the list item row? I think the TextView you're using is not supporting multiline. Allowing multi-line can will do the job I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use **wrap_content** on your list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<CheckBox..
</RelativeLayout>
```

or set **height** size

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <CheckBox..
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i actually am using - android:layout_height="wrap_content" - in my list xml file, and changing the height will change it to ALL cells together, witch is not something i want to do

Comment: change on your item layout not listview layout @user2560571

Comment: my Item layout is wrap content...still it doesn't change it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing the alignment to the bottom of the Layout in the costume layout.